# Video capture PROPID parameters in openCV

Tags: opencv, python-3.x, video-capture

I am using Python 3.4 and opencv(64 bits). My question is about property identifier parameters such as CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, or CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT for video capture. The full documentation for this is here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=get#cv2.VideoCapture.get. My program works fine when I hard code these numbers in but it does not recognize any of the terms given in the documentation.  I read some earlier posts that these were available in cv but are not available in cv2 library. Has there been any updates? I can not find anything else here... I don't like using hard-coded numbers.  Any advice?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I must add that I am new to Python.  I read that I must have import cv2.cv as cv but I get this error: ImportError: No module named 'cv2.cv'; 'cv2' is not a package

Comment: I am having the same problem. I think in the documentation you posted they are listed in the order of their integer identifier. So a workaround would be to just define them yourself `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC=0` etc. I would be very interested in the proper solution, though.

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled upon the properties while looking through related posts on the internet.

For Python OpenCV 3, they are directly in `cv2` module but have to be accessed without the leading `CV_`. For example the two properties you mentioned can be accessed as:

```
cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH
cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT
```

A working example would be:

```
import numpy
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("examplevid.mp4")
height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
width  = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
```

Note that this only applies to OpenCV 3. For older versions of OpenCV (i.e. 2.X.X) the `cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT` syntax should work.

Comment: Seconding this, for OpenCV 3.0.0 (cv2)